# AMP - amp-list Out of Viewport loading

Tags: html, css, amp-html, google-amp

this is my question:

If I load an AMP-list it will not load anything out of the viewport, but my whole intend is to have a overflow-y possible table. As you can see in the following gifs

I tried out every possible **layout** setting.

How it **should** look like: https://gfycat.com/RelievedSplendidAmericangoldfinch

How it looks like: https://gfycat.com/NauticalDimHogget

Comment: it's difficult to offer advice without seeing the actual code